# File path doesn't work as expected

Tags: php, mysql

I have a tiny test cms. These are the directories:

```
admin
--css
----admin.css
--js
--tinymce
--index.php
--functions.php
--logout.php
--blogadmin.php
--imagesadmin.php
--videosadmin.php
--connectadmin.php
--maincontentadmin.php
--settingsadmin.php
css
--cssimages
--mainstyle.css
js
images
plugins
--blog.php
--images.php
--videos.php
--connect.php
uploads
config.php
index.php
mysql.php
```

The `admin/functions.php` needs the `mysql.php`.

```
require("../mysql.php");
```

It works.

The `plugins/connect.php` needs the `admin/functions.php`

```
require("../admin/functions.php");
```

The `plugins/connect.php` is included in the `index.php` And the files in the admin folder using the `functions.php` too.

It doesn't work. Why?

Comment: Where is `plugins/connect.php` is included to?

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question.

Comment: Then you need to try this `admin/functions.php` only

Comment: I tried: Warning: require(../mysql.php): failed to open stream in the functions.php

Comment: The admin files using the functions.php too, so I can't use require(mysql.php)

Comment: how it doesnt work , what errors you getting ?

Comment: Warning: require(../mysql.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\cms\admin\functions.php on line 2


    Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '../mysql.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp\www\cms\admin\functions.php on line 2

Comment: is right path this `C:\wamp\www\cms\admin\functions.php` ?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are including `plugins/connect.php` from `index.php`, the code from `connect.php` is being run inside `index.php`. So the path you are using needs to be `admin/functions.php`, which is relative to `index.php`.

If this isn't an option for you, because `plugins/connect.php` gets included from multiple places, you should consider using absolute paths include your include. For example, use `C:\wamp\www\cms\admin\functions.php` instead.

Comment: It's ok on localhost, but I won't use it on localhost forever

Comment: You can still use the absolute paths on another machine. As long as you have to proper path, you should be able to include with just about any host.

Comment: How can I check the root directory if somebody installs my cms?

Comment: If you make a php script, put `<?php echo __FILE__; ?>` in it, and access it from a browser, it should print out the full path to the file you are accessing. That should help you figure out the absolute path on the server.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found is to copy the `mysql.php` in the admin folder and change this line:

`require("../mysql.php");`

in the `functions.php` to this:

`require("mysql.php");`

I don't like it, but it works.